# moment checking start and finish times are valid

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working on a form at the moment that takes a start time and a finish time, I need to check that,

a) The start is prior to the finish time
b) The finish time is after the start time

I am having some problems if the finish time is after midnight, as that would be classed as before the start time? For example, start time of 21.00 end time of 03.00 would be invalid due to moment thinking 03.00 become before 21.00?

I have found the `isBefore()` and is `isAfter()` methods but I don't think they will help me alot?

Here is my code for clarity,

```
const [hours, minutes] = startTime.split(":");
const [hours, minutes] = endTime.split(":");

let startTimeWithDate = moment().set({hours, minutes}).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
let endTimeWithDate = moment().set({hours, minutes}).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

let ms = moment(startTimeWithDate).diff(moment(endTimeWithDate));

if(ms < 0) { 
    //invalid
} else {
    //valid
}
```

My problem is that a start time, could start at 07:00 and finish at 22:00 this currently returns as invalid, the other problem is that if the end time is past midnight with my current logic the end time is then saved being before the start time. Is there away to add a day to a moment date is the time passed too it is passed midnight?

So the rule should be, that if the end time is past midnight, but before the start time, it should be processed as the next day i.e someone could work a 18:00 -> 02:00 shift (today at 18:00 until tomorrow at 02:00)

Comment: You need dates to go with the times if you expect any code to interpret 21:00 as being before 03:00.

Comment: You need to have date to identify the next date. Or you need to write a logic if start time is greater than 12 and if end time is less than 12 then mark it as valid. But this will lead to error.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have add some clarification with my current code.

Comment: Dear @Udders, actually, `let startTimeWithDate = moment().set({hours, minutes}).format("YYYY-MM-DD");`   and `let endTimeWithDate = moment().set({hours, minutes}).format("YYYY-MM-DD");` should show the same date, and that fact that you have set hours and minutes don't impact on it.

Comment: For solving this issue the date is required. For example `startTime` should be something like `2021-04-05 22:00` instead of `22:00`.

Answer (score 0):

You need date and time information to compare the values. In general, if you are receiving start and finish from the UI, just format it as you need to show on the UI, but also save the full date and time to process them.

If you are using moment.js, for maximum precision, `.valueOf()`, which should return the value by milliseconds. And so you can just compare

a. `moment(start).valueOf() < moment(finish).valueOf()`

b. `moment(finish).valueOf() < moment(start).valueOf()`

Comment: Dear @Udders, actually, `let startTimeWithDate = moment().set({hours, minutes}).format("YYYY-MM-DD");`   and `let endTimeWithDate = moment().set({hours, minutes}).format("YYYY-MM-DD");` should show the same date, and that fact that you have set hours and minutes don't impact on it.

Comment: Note that `isAfter` and `isBefore` are both [granular to the millisecond by default](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/), so using `valueOf` gives you the same precision as `isAfter` with no second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need *both* the date and time components, in moment variables. Then you can use `isAfter` to verify the end time is after the start time. Now, because the code adds a day if the end time is before the start time, the only way this will fail is when the the times are equal. I'll let you decide if that's what you want or not.

```js
function isGoodTimePair(start, end) {
  const maxWorkHours = 12;
  const [startHour, startMin] = start.split(':').map(i => +i);
  const [endHour, endMin] = end.split(':').map(i => +i);
  const startTimeWithDate = moment().set({
    hours: startHour,
    minutes: startMin,
    seconds: 0,
    milliseconds: 0
  });
  const shouldAddDay = (endH, startH) => (endH < startH && ((endH + 24) - startH) < maxWorkHours);
  const endTimeWithDate = moment()
    .add(shouldAddDay(endHour, startHour) ? 1 : 0, 'days')
    .set({
      hours: endHour,
      minutes: endMin,
      seconds: 0,
      milliseconds: 0
    });
  const diff = endTimeWithDate.diff(startTimeWithDate, 'hours');
  return diff > 0 && diff <= maxWorkHours;
}
console.log(isGoodTimePair('21:00', '03:00'));
console.log(isGoodTimePair('21:00', '22:00'));
console.log(isGoodTimePair('21:00', '21:00'));
console.log(isGoodTimePair('01:00', '21:00'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Dear @Heretic Monkey as I got from the question if we have for example `start=18:00` and `end=14:00` the function should return false. Because The finish time is not after the start time. So when you are adding one day in the case when `end < start` you miss this part.

Comment: @CyberEternal From the text of my answer: "Now, because the code adds a day if the end time is before the start time, the only way this will fail is when the the times are equal. I'll let you decide if that's what you want or not." The OP needs to explain what the rules are for when an end time being less than a start time is okay and when it is not. This answer is just about getting the date in there, and how to add a day conditionally.

Comment: Uhh. I missed the text above. My bad :).  Anyway, we can not determine the exact day based on the time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for this example, I am indeed looking for it to fail is the start time is later than end time though, but I need to allow for night shift, so for example, 

>18:00 - 00:00 would be fine
> 05:00 - 04:00 would not as that looks like a 23 hour working pattern

Comment: @Udders You need to edit your question with the exact rules of when the times should change over.

Comment: @Udders So here's the problem with your requirement. All times are "past midnight", except midnight. 18:00 is 18 hours past midnight. Heck, even 23:00 is 23 hours past midnight. So the question, now that we know these are work shifts, is what is the maximum work shift length that a user can enter? That's how we should program the adding of days; so just change `endHour < startHour` to `endHour < startHour && (endHour + 24) - startHour < maxWorkHours`, substituting `maxWorkHours` with that maximum shift length in hours.

Comment: For instance, I've updated my answer to use 12 hours as the maximum shift length. I'm saying that 0 or > 12 are invalid. You can modify as you see fit.